# Custom templates, custom post type, and single page problems

Tags: wordpress, templates, posts

I have set up a custom post type for a few sub sections of the website I am currently working on in wordpress. I need the custom post types to feed onto a template (which I have working) but I have a few questions and non working things. The read more link is not working, as in not showing up at all even? Also when I click the title links n the posts to go to the full post, they go to the correct url but there is no content in the body. I'm thinking I need to add more in the custom template.

Here is the template code :

```
<?php
/* Template Name:News */
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="decade1">
<ul id="news_list">
<?php global $post; query_posts( 'post_type=news&orderby=ID&order=desc' ); while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<li>
<div class="fea_del">
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <p><?php the_field('post_content',$post->ID); ?></p>
    <a <?php $p=get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?> href="<?php echo $p; ?>" class="entire_job">Read More</a>
</div>
</li>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The most important issue is the posts not showing up on their individual pages. Thanks!!

Comment: Why global $post; there? If you do that then inside the while loop $post will reference to that global var, not the $post inside each loop. The other thing about "templates", first of all, one thing is a PAGE template like the one in your example, and another thing is a theme template for displaying single post types, in your case will be "single-news.php".

Comment: I'm trying to fix a website for a friend, I dont ever really work with wordpress so honestly, I have no idea about the global variable. The custom single template send me in the right direction though, thank you! Would you happen to know how to display just the title and content on the single post? thank you!!

Comment: Just use the_title() and the_content() inside the loop.